# validate string based on a format

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that must be on the following format:

XXXX-XX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-X

where X is an integer. The number of integers don't matter. I just need to make sure that the string:

- starts and ends with an integer
- contains only integers separated by dashes

what would be the easiest way to validate that?

Comment: Regular expressions will do the job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This regexp should do the trick. It uses a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid matching multiple dashes in a row.

```
^\d(\d|(?<!-)-)*\d$|^\d$

 ^        ^       ^    ^
 |        |       |    -- is a single digit, or
 |        |       ------- ends with a digit
 |        ----------------consists on digits or dashes not preceded by dashes
 ---------------------starts with a digit
```

Here is a C# code that illustrates its use (also on [ideone](http://ideone.com/H2qKs)):

```
var r = new Regex("^\\d(\\d|(?<!-)-)*\\d$|^\\d$");
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("1-2-3"));
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("1-222-3333"));
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("123"));
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("1-2-3-"));
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("1"));
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("-11-2-3-"));
```

Comment: you have an extra ) on your answer. The correct would be ^\d(\d|(?<!-)-)*\d$|^\d$

Comment: @Diego You are right, the sample I linked at ideone does not have this extra parenthesis. I edited the answer, thanks!

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was the one who deals with dasehs in a row. thanks a lot

Comment: @Diego Admittedly, your question was harder than it looked: a very simple initial expression grew quickly to accommodate the corner cases. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 9):

Use a regular expression.

```
^\d[-0-9]+\d$
```

This assumes the string is at least three characters long.

Breakdown:

```
^    - match start of string
\d   - match a digit
[    - start of character class containing:
-      - a dash
0-9    - 0 to 9
]    - end of character class
+    - match one or more of the previous
\d   - match a digit
$    - match end of string
```

You can change the `+` to `*` to make 2 digit strings valid, and add an alternation to make 1 digit strings valid as well:

```
^(\d|\d[-0-9]*\d)$
```

Note: In .NET, `\d` will match *any* Unicode digit (so, for example, Arabic digits will match) - if you don't want that, replace `\d` with `[0-9]` in every place.

Comment: +1 very good thanks. Only issue is that it doesn't validate 1 or 12

Comment: @Diego - No, I did post the assumption that this assumes 3 characters. You can use alternation to match for 1 and 2 digits. Answer updated.

Comment: thanks Oded. Just for your info, it still validates 1--1 (dashes in a row). But that's fine, dasblinkenlight already posted an working solution. Thanks again for your time

Comment: @Diego - Yes it would. Both the requirement for 1 and 2 digit strings and that multiple dashes are _not_ valid are not stated in your question. You should be more comprehensive if you wish to get good answers fast.

Answer (score 5):

you can write a regular expression that does the trick.

Than you can use that regular expression to validate your string

```
^ ---->Start of a string. 
$ ---->End of a string. 
. ----> Any character (except \n newline) 
{...}----> Explicit quantifier notation. 
[...] ---->Explicit set of characters to match. 
(...) ---->Logical grouping of part of an expression. 
* ---->0 or more of previous expression. 
+ ---->1 or more of previous expression. 
? ---->0 or 1 of previous expression; also forces minimal matching when an expression might match several strings within a search string. 
\ ---->Preceding one of the above, it makes it a literal instead of a special character. Preceding a special matching character, see below. 
\w ----> matches any word character, equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9] 
\W ----> matches any non word character, equivalent to [^a-zA-Z0-9]. 
\s ----> matches any white space character, equivalent to [\f\n\r\v] 
\S----> matches any non-white space characters, equivalent to [^\f\n\r\v] 
\d ----> matches any decimal digits, equivalent to [0-9] 
\D----> matches any non-digit characters, equivalent to [^0-9] 

\a ----> Matches a bell (alarm) \u0007. 
\b ----> Matches a backspace \u0008 if in a [] character class; otherwise, see the note following this table. 
\t ---->Matches a tab \u0009. 
\r ---->Matches a carriage return \u000D. 
\v ---->Matches a vertical tab \u000B. 
\f ---->Matches a form feed \u000C. 
\n ---->Matches a new line \u000A. 
\e ---->Matches an escape \u001B 

$number ----> Substitutes the last substring matched by group number number (decimal). 
${name} ----> Substitutes the last substring matched by a (? ) group. 
$$ ----> Substitutes a single "$" literal. 
$& ----> Substitutes a copy of the entire match itself. 
$` ----> Substitutes all the text of the input string before the match. 
$' ----> Substitutes all the text of the input string after the match. 
$+ ----> Substitutes the last group captured. 
$_ ----> Substitutes the entire input string. 

(?(expression)yes|no) ----> Matches yes part if expression matches and no part will be ommited.
```

more info at

http://geekswithblogs.net/brcraju/archive/2003/10/23/235.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression is probably the way to go this might help:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html